# match.path prop to respect basename(/defaultPathname) in root URL - https://example.com/defaultPathname

Tags: reactjs, react-router

CRA 2 and React Router v4

Our app url is in this format : `"https://subdomain.subdomain.domain.com/defaultPathname/"`

Settings in App.js: `<BrowserRouter basename="/defaultPathname"/>`

I have problem that when i use react-router `match.path` *prop* it contains only `/newlink` and not `/defaultPathname/newlink` hence i can't open new tab because it points only to `/newlink` instead of `/defaultPathname/newlink`

How to achieve that programatically without using `<Link />` component?

Comment: isn't that expected? well if that's a problem for you then why not just create a function that will strip out that problem?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you can use history.createHref() to apply the basename to a URL generated via generatePath or any other means:

```
const pathname = generatePath(routeUrl, params);

const url = history.createHref({
  pathname
});

// url includes basename
```

So hence i solved it like this

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/defaultPathname">
 {children}
</BrowserRouter>
```

Component.js

```
const Component = ({ match, history, children, linkId }) => {
  const pathname = useMemo(() => generatePath(`${match.path}/${linkId}`), [linkId, match.path])
  const newLink = history.createHref({ pathname })

  return (
    <a
      href={newLink}
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        history.push({
          pathname,
        })
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}
```